# how to prepend page name to domain name, i.e. blog.example.com instead of example.com/blog

Tags: url-rewriting

I've tried googling for the answer, but I think I'm using the wrong terminology because nothing is coming up.

So I want to be able to take:

```
example.com/blog
```

and change it to:

```
blog.example.com
```

Comment: Is this a web server question or a programming question? What language are you using? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a "subdomain." What server type is your site hosted on? (Windows, Linux, etc). Based on that, the next steps to setting up a subdomain will be pretty clear.

In some cases you'll need to add a "C-NAME" record with your Domain Name registrar, so check with them to make sure subdomains are allowed.

If you have a Linux-based host (which most likely runs the Apache web server), follow these steps:

http://www.santiagolizardo.com/article/how-to-setup-wildcard-subdomains-in-linux/64001

Comment: Thanks man. That's exactly what I was looking for. It's amazing how hard it can be to find answers if you don't know the terminology, but I got it figured it out now with your help. Thanks again